# how to implement bookmark or favourite functionality in ios app

Tags: ios, core-data

In my iphone app,i would like to implement bookmark functionality.Like,there is table view containing a list of "sayings".I will be placing a button inside tableview cells.On clicking that button,the content of that cell should go to another table view,which will be my bookmark view.And every time i close and reopen that app,those bookmarked sayings should be there.Heard that we have to use core data here.But i am new to this development environment,so i dont have  an idea about ,how to implement this.
Can any one help me..

Answer (score 1):

Its simple whenever user taps the table cell change the color of the table cell to show user that cell has bookmarked. Meanwhile create another array containing the bookmark table cell, so whenever user taps the cell add it to that array. If u want persistance storage use sqlite database to store the bookmarked values.

Whenever you open application before loading the values check if it is previously bookmarked. If yes then change the color of the cell else keep it as it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use core data its okay, you are just going to store a list of bookmarked items so you would probably use a array.

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarksArray= put in all items.
```

Put in these two functions for easy and centralized use of NSUserDefaults

```
/**
 *  This method helps to set values to NSUserDefaults
 */

+(void)userDefaultsSetObject:(id)userObject forKey:(NSString *)userKey
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:userObject forKey:userKey];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}

/**
 *  This method helps to get values from NSUserDefaults
 */

+(id)userDefaultsGetObjectForKey:(NSString *)userKey
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [userDefaults objectForKey:userKey];
}
```

And now do something like this to save your bookmarked array, every time a change happens in the bookmarks.

```
[self userDefaultsSetObject:bookmarksArray forKey:@"BookMarkedItems"];
```

Next time do something like this to get it back.

```
NSMutableArray *oldBookmarksArray=[self userDefaultsGetObjectForKey:@"BookMarkedItems"];
```